# Embedded C# lambda expression as function parameter

Tags: c#, lambda, windows-phone

Does anyone know what problem is with the below piece of code, which cannot compile in VS2013?

```
GenericCommand.AddHandlerFactory("MyKey", (cmd, action) =>
{
  return (command) =>
  {
    var result = new SuccessResult() { ResultText = "some example text" };
    result.Send(command.Configuration);
  };
});
```

The prototype of AddHandlerFactory is :

```
public static void AddHandlerFactory(string key, Func<GenericCommand, Action> handlerFactory)
```

When compiles in VS2013, it shows

> A local variable named command cannot be declared in this scope
> because it would give a different meaning to command .... ....

and

> Delegate System.Func
> WindowsPhoneTestFramework.Client.AutomationClient.Remote.GenericCommand,
> System.Action does not take 2 arguments

More detail of the source code is at:
https://github.com/Expensify/WindowsPhoneTestFramework/blob/master/Client/AutomationClient/Remote/GenericCommand.cs

## EDIT1 rename the first command to cmd, the first error msg is resolved. But it still cannot compile.

The error msg is :

> cannot convert lambda expression to delegate  type  Delegate
> System.Func
> WindowsPhoneTestFramework.Client.AutomationClient.Remote.GenericCommand,
> System.Action because some of the return types in the block are not
> implicitly convertible to the delegate return type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two parameters sharing the same name :

- `(command, action) =>` is one action with a param nammed `command`
- `return (command) =>` is another action, with another param nammed `command`

So you have to rename one of the two param names.

As @Dirk explained, you return an `Action<T>` instead of an `Action`. So you can try this :

```
GenericCommand.AddHandlerFactory("MyKey", (cmd, action) =>
{
  return () =>
  {
    var result = new SuccessResult() { ResultText = "some example text" };
    result.Send(cmd.Configuration);
  };
});
```

Comment: That's not the only thing. The return value of the lambda should be an Action, but it's an Action<Something>.